# Как вывеcти sum () в ряд вместе с user_id

Tags: php, sql

Хочу вывести общее количество просмотров у каждого пользователя (просмотров его постов). Делаю запрос в БД, все показывает. При выполнении такой функции пользователи отображаются, но количество просмотров идет в виде (1668115581132331241612389932289). Как сделать, чтобы кол просмотров (views) было идентично каждому пользователю, например, user_id1 - (его просмотры), user_id2 (его просмотры) и т.д?

```
function Wo_FeaturedUsers($limit = '', $type = '')
{
    global $wo, $sqlConnect;
    if ($wo['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = array();
    $logged_user_id = $wo['user']['user_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
   {
        $query_one = " SELECT `user_id`, SUM(views)
FROM `Wo_Posts`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 90
DAY ) AND page_id = 0 GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY  SUM(`views`) DESC LIMIT 30
";
        $sql = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, $query_one);
        while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

$data[] = Wo_UserData($fetched_data['user_id']);
echo $fetched_data['SUM(views)'];
        } 
    } 
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Если нужно КОЛИЧЕСТВО просмотров, то разумнее использовать COUNT(), а не SUM()... какой смысл суммировать идентификаторы?

Comment: мне главное вывести апотом разберусь)

Comment: Ну так выводи. Но выводи что нужно, а не что под руку попалось. Замени в своём запросе SUM(views) на COUNT(views)...

Comment: @Akina [щедро делясь своими знаниями, помните, что все мы собрались здесь, чтобы вместе учиться. Будьте доброжелательными и терпеливыми, особенно с теми, кто может не обладать всеми знаниями, которые есть у вас](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @Dmitry Учёба предполагает как минимум попытку понять ответ.

Comment: @РоманРоманович У вас как то странно выглядит функция, список id пользователей она возврашает как массив тому кто ее вызвал и при этом печатает все количества сразу на экран. по факту выходит, что она сначала печатает все количества, а потом тот код, который ее вызывал, отдельно печатает пользователей (или что он с ними делает). Вам надо принять решение, кто осуществляет вывод на экран и делать это в одном месте. А для этого возможно, вернуть двумерный массив, в котором будут и id и количества

Comment: @Akina А тут проблема вообще не в SQL. Если views - это количество просмотров (а судя по названию это так и есть (почему вы решили, что это id)), то sum тут на месте

Comment: @РоманРоманович P.S. Если не разберетесь, то приведите в вопросе и тот код, который вызывает данную функцию и собственно осуществляет печать пользователей

Comment: печать пользователей вызывает Wo_Userdata [user_id]

Comment: пользователи выводятся без проблем , но столбец views выводится не идентично id пользователю

Comment: в базе этот запрос выглядет так

Comment: user_id(1)  views - 16000 а при выводе чреез php пользователи отдельно а views в строку 160001200013001500014000